# How to hide double.NaN values in ScottPlot?

Tags: c#, winforms, scottplot

I use ScottPlot to visualize some data in WinForms. I have some null values which i use NaN instead to hide them and not to break data flow, so I want to hide them. However, in ScottPlot, they are shown like infinity, it makes a long long spike at the middle of chart, how can I set it up correctly to just ignore NaN values and hide them? Thank you

Edit:
By hiding NaNs, I mean leave a gap in chart instead of any value for a NaN.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow, for us to be able to help you the most, we need to see a [minimal, complete and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

That said, I'd suggest looking at Linq, and more precisely, the Where Method, which, assuming you're working on a collection could allow you to filter out the NaN values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, buy I don't want to filter them, I just want to have gaps in chart, LiveCharts has this feature, it just not draws NaNs as any value and leaves a gap there.

Comment: ScottPlot does not treat NaNs as undrawed points. If you want a point to not be drawn, you have to remove it from the input.

Also, it would be worth saying which plottable you are using, as for example Signal plots require having a uniform distance between points, so you cannot have a gap at all (you would be required to use SignalXY or a Scatter plot).

Comment: @Ben Thank you for your response. So it seems ScottPlot does not support the feature I want, LiveCharts does, but it is relatively slow.

Comment: @editali ScottPlot has chosen not to prescribe an interpretation to NaNs (such as removing them) because from the definition of NaN as not a number combined with ease of debugging means that ScottPlot does not do this, and under certain circumstances throws if a NaN value is in the given data. i.e. the philosophy is NaN is not valid data, and thus a user should not expect a valid plot (let alone a specific valid plot).

This *is* controversial sometimes, if you're curious the discussion in https://github.com/swharden/ScottPlot/discussions/645 touches on this issue with reference to heatmaps.

Comment: @Ben Thank you dear Ben for clarification. I am aware of philosophy of NaNs and thats exactly why I want to be a gap there not a value such as infinity! There are multiple charts laid over each other, some of them contain invalid data, which are marked as NaN, but others contain valid data exactly at that index, so logically NaNs should be hidden there, not an infinity spike! So, regardless of great performance of ScottPlot I have to give up over that, however I will check on it time to time, maybe someday devs changed their minds.